# vscode file icons

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-icons

I am looking for vscode file-icons like Atom file-icons https://atom.io/packages/file-icons if vscode is built using an atom shell, is it possible to use extensions such as Atom file-icons with vscode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to use extensions but we plan to support this in the future. See also: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752408-plugin-system

Comment: The August release of VS Code (available in September) includes a new Contribution Point for icon extensions. There is already a [draft of documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10804) available and [a simple demo extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10600).

Answer (score 4):

Although as Benjamin says it is not supported I've just created this extension that will let you have Sublime icons in your vscode. Note that the extension injects code into two vscode files. Read the project disclaimer.

You can find it here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons